# How to make advanced deeplinks in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

In the event React Native app for now I use firebase deep links... but it does not give me enough power.

For example, the user (who doesn't have installed the app yet) receives an invite link to an event and by clicking on a link user goes to App Store first to install the app.

The goal is to transfer the user to a proper event that connects with the link pressed after the app is installed and opened the first time

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: https://branch.io/ does all that for you. Will redirect to app stores when a deeplink is handled and not installed. Also multiple ways to retreive first install params from within the code. The branch io link also with params & auto creates a QR from it etc. etc.

Comment: Firebase Dynamic Link fits your needs perfectly, please explain why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Joe199382  So I just can’t figure out how to use firebase for this, if you can, please tell me where I can read about such an implementation. Thanks

Comment: Hope this can help you, https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage